# Referencing Object/Model field with dictionary key

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm looping through a dictionary that has keys that match the fields in an `ObjectModel`.

With the value from that dictionary, I query an address and gather some data that I want to then save in the `Object`. My hope is to use the key from the dictionary to reference the field within the object.

I'm having a hard time explaining this with text so I hope the example code below showcases what I'm trying to do:

```
example_dict = {
    "key": "value",
    "second_key": "second_value"
}

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    second_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
}

object_example = ExampleModel()

for key, value in example_dict:
    data = doDataRequest(value)
    object_example[key] = data

object_example.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
You were also trying to set an attribute of a class as if it were a dict, try to use built in methods such as getattr and setaddr to access those. Look here:

Visit https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#setattr

I would recommend to try iterating differently on the dictionary, you could try something like this below, I think this is where your issue is coming in. If not let me know!

`for key, value in example_dict.items():
    data = doDataRequest(key)
    //Use setattr
    setattr(object_example, key, data)`

And on another note, why use a dict for holding key value pairs if you are not using the value? perhaps try an array with your keys?

Comment: I was suggested to use the built-in function `settattr` which seems to be working except for my DateTimeField is bugging out. As for the dictionary, I am actually using the value, it was a typo - I've since corrected it!

Comment: is USE_TZ=True in your settings.py?

Comment: If thats the case look into pytz and use the correctly formatted datetime object. There is a core django contributor who wrote this article, I attended his talk in San Diego and it was mind blowing. Visit: https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2018/05/25/09-its-about-time.html

Comment: If you did not add the .items() in the for loop, that might be why date time is not working. Good luck :)